# `R` not working in `anaconda 3` on `Mojave`

Tags: r, conda

I just installed `R` on `Mojave` in `Anaconda 3` using:

```
conda install r-base r-essentials r-irkernel
```

When I type `r` I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I followed the instructions in this [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6183) but it did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making a new env should be a cleaner install process and is the best practice. For example,

```
conda create -n r_40 r-base=4.0 r-essentials r-irkernel
```

<sub>**Note:** I recommend always explicitly specifying a version (including minor) for `r-base` since this will help constrain `conda update --all` to stay within the R version. If you need to change the R version, then it is almost always more efficacious to create a new environment.</sub>

Generally, the more you can avoid installing in **base** env, the better your Conda experience will be.

Answer (score -1):

If your Mac is running under zsh shell, try to switch to sh

> chsh -s /bin/sh